# BeautifulSoup - Misspelled Class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape location data from https://www.wellstar.org/locations/pages/default.aspx and while I was inspecting the source, I noticed that the class for the hospital's address is sometimes spelled with an extra 'd' - 'adddress' vs 'address'.  Is there a way to account for this difference in the following code?  I have attempted to incorporate an `if` statement to test the length of the `address` object but I only get the addresses associated with the 'adddress' class.  I feel that I am close yet out of ideas.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://www.wellstar.org/locations/pages/default.aspx")

for table in soup.findAll("table",class_="s4-wpTopTable"):
    for type in table.findAll("h3"):
        type = type.get_text()
    for name in table.findAll("div",class_="PurpleBackgroundHeading"):
        name = name.get_text()
    address=""
    for address in table.findAll("div",class_="WS_Location_Adddress"):
            address = address.get_text(separator=" ")
    if len(address)==0:
        for address in table.findAll("div",class_="WS_Location_Address"):
            address = address.get_text(separator = " ")
            print(type, name, address)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is great at adapting, you can use a regular expression:

```
for address in table.find_all("div", class_=re.compile(r"WS_Location_Ad{2,}ress")):
```

where `d{2,}` would match `d` 2 or more times.

---

Or, you can just specify a *list* of classes:

```
for address in table.find_all("div", class_=["WS_Location_Address", "WS_Location_Adddress"]):
```

Comment: Both excellent choices - I am intrigued/intimidated by regular expressions, to be honest.  This may be reason to spend some time learning the operators.